# How to post XML data from iOS app to web?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I am trying to send some data in XML format to my web page where I can register the user.

I have tried two ways and with both the ways I felt to grab the data.

**Way-1**

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://****.com/iphone/csi/register.php?choice=register";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *highScoreData = [NSMutableData data];
    [highScoreData appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [highScoreData appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<user_name>%@</user_name", @"test"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [highScoreData appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<password>%@</password>", @"test"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [highScoreData appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"</xml>"] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody: highScoreData];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request
                                                                delegate: self];
```

**Way-2**

```
    NSString * xmlString = @"<test><message>Hello</message></test>";        
    NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demos4clients.com/iphone/csi/register.php?choice=register"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
    [serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse * serviceResponse;
    NSError * serviceError;
    serviceResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];
```

How can I find the reason for this error?

Comment: try to use one string instead of 4 or 5 strings in method1

Comment: You can use https://github.com/groue/GRMustache it's simply modele template file for manipulate xml data

Comment: @tdelepine can i send xml data through this??

Comment: The GRMustaphe component do not send the data. He prepare a string xml dom through a template file. The template file can be feeding by an custom IOS class and keyPaths access. You can chose the data encoding to use

Comment: then lot of work to do with that.

Comment: This question references an error that occurred when posting data. However, I am not sure that the actual error text has been provided, and thus it may be unanswerable in its present condition. Although this is an old question, it should nevertheless be put on hold if it is not answerable.